# Norm conserving LDA fully relativistic pseudopotential in quantum espresso

Tags: quantum-espresso, pseudopotentials

For my calculation, I need fully relativistic LDA Norm conserving pseudopotential. I have searched for this in the existing library like PseudoDojo, SSSP, SG15, PSLibrary etc., but failed. However, I am getting fully relativistic ultrasoft LDA pseudopotentials. Does anybody know where to get fully relativistic LDA pseudos?

Answer (score 2):

[This GitHub repository](https://github.com/wu2meng3/ONCVPseudoPack) collects optimized norm-conserving Vanderbilt pseudopotentials, both scalar and full relativistic, generated from LDA, PBE, and PBEsol. Looks like for LDA you can use either the Sg15 or Abinit ones!